# Tetris Movement - Implementation

Tags: xna, game-mechanics, input, game-loop

I'm developing a Tetris clone and working on the input at the moment.

When I was prototyping, movement was triggered by releasing a directional key. However, in most Tetris games I've played the movement is a bit more complex.

> When a directional key is pressed, the shape moves one space in that direction. After a short interval, if the key is still held down, the shape starts moving in the direction continuously until the key is released.
>
> In the case of the down key being pressed, there is no pause between the initial movement and the subsequent continuous movement.

I've come up with a solution, and it works well, but it's totally over-engineered. Hey, at least I can recognize when things are getting silly, right? :)

```
    public class TetrisMover
    {
        List registeredKeys;
        Dictionary continuousPressedTime;
        Dictionary totalPressedTime;
        Dictionary initialIntervals;
        Dictionary continousIntervals;
        Dictionary keyActions;
        Dictionary initialActionDone;
        KeyboardState currentKeyboardState;

        public TetrisMover()
        {
            *snip*
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

            foreach (Keys currentKey in registeredKeys)
            {
                if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(currentKey))
                {
                    continuousPressedTime[currentKey] = TimeSpan.Zero;
                    totalPressedTime[currentKey] = TimeSpan.Zero;
                    initialActionDone[currentKey] = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (initialActionDone[currentKey] == false)
                    {
                        keyActions[currentKey]();
                        initialActionDone[currentKey] = true;
                    }

                    totalPressedTime[currentKey] += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;

                    if (totalPressedTime[currentKey] >= initialIntervals[currentKey])
                    {
                        continuousPressedTime[currentKey] += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
                        if (continuousPressedTime[currentKey] >= continousIntervals[currentKey])
                        {
                            keyActions[currentKey]();
                            continuousPressedTime[currentKey] = TimeSpan.Zero;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void RegisterKey(Keys key, TimeSpan initialInterval, TimeSpan continuousInterval, Action keyAction)
        {
            if (registeredKeys.Contains(key))
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    string.Format("The key %s is already registered.", key));

            registeredKeys.Add(key);
            continuousPressedTime.Add(key, TimeSpan.Zero);
            totalPressedTime.Add(key, TimeSpan.Zero);
            initialIntervals.Add(key, initialInterval);
            continousIntervals.Add(key, continuousInterval);
            keyActions.Add(key, keyAction);
            initialActionDone.Add(key, false);
        }

        public void UnregisterKey(Keys key)
        {
            *snip*
        }
    }
```

I'm updating it every frame, and this is how I'm registering keys for movement:

```
            tetrisMover.RegisterKey(
                Keys.Left, keyHoldStartSpecialInterval, keyHoldMovementInterval,
                () => { Move(Direction.Left); });

            tetrisMover.RegisterKey(
                Keys.Right, keyHoldStartSpecialInterval, keyHoldMovementInterval,
                () => { Move(Direction.Right); });

            tetrisMover.RegisterKey(
                Keys.Down, TimeSpan.Zero, keyHoldMovementInterval,
                () => { PerformGravity(); });
```

Issues that this doesn't address:

- If both left and right are held down,
  the shape moves back and forth really
  quick.
- If a directional key is held down and
  the turn finishes and the shape is
  replaced by a new one, the new one
  will move quickly in that direction
  instead of the little pause it is
  supposed to have.

I could fix the issues, but I think it will make the solution even worse. How would you implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a simple key repeating algorithm. This is how I usually do it.

```
FRAMES_FOR_FIRST_PRESS = 4;
FRAMES_FOR_OTHER_PRESS = 1;

key_pending_frames = -1;
```

now, for every frame:

```
function OnFrame()
{
    if (IsKeyPressed())
    {
        if (key_pending_frames < 0) // not pressed
        {
            key_pending_frames = FRAMES_FOR_FIRST_PRESS;
        }
        key_pending_frames--;
        if (key_pending_frames == 0)
        {
            DoYourAction();
            key_pending_frames = FRAMES_FOR_OTHER_PRESS;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        key_pending_frames = -1;
    }
}
```

You'd need a key_pending_frames for each key you want, and you can reset any key's counter just by setting its variable to -1.

Note that for non-fixed frame lengths, you can use clock ticks, or another time interval structure you have. You just have to make sure your non-pressed value is unreachable by simply decrementing the counter. To be on the safe side, you can simply add a `bool key_pressed` for each key.